# How to check if css property is set?

Tags: jquery

As per the title really.

If notice that if I check `$(elem).css('margin-top')` it returns `0px` even though I haven't explicitly set this style, either inline or in a stylesheet.

Basically I am setting the margin each time I hover over an element (to vertically align some content) so would rather just do this once.

I can't set the alignment on page load because the elements are hidden (display:none) so it needs to be done at the time they are displayed.

Comment: Actually the margin is set and working even when it is not displayed. http://jsfiddle.net/ZnbCn/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(!$(elem).data('hasSetMargin')){
    $(elem).css('margin-top', someValue);
    $(elem).data('hasSetMargin', true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What's the problem with setting it several times?

It looks like you're trying to early-optimize your code.

Comment: I wouldn't class this as early optimization. My requirements are to set it once. If there is a simple way of doing that rather than performing the margin calculation on every hover, then that is the option I would like to take.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to tell because there are many sources which affect the value of a style such as `margin-top`.

However, you don't need to tell really because:

1. Setting it more than once should do no harm in your case.
2. You can improve your code by adding/removing/toggling HTML classes (`addClass`/`removeClass`/`toggleClass`) and styling the elements with pure static CSS (using class selectors) *instead of* setting the styles yourself. This has the added benefit of making your code readable.

Regarding the readability -- what would you rather read? This:

```
function() {
    $(selector).css('margin-top', '10px').css('border', '2px red solid');
}
```

or this:

```
function() {
    $(selector).addClass('update-pending');
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't use classes. The margin is calculated based on the contents of an element so it's not a question of just adding a css class. Whilst you say there is no harm setting the margin more than once, it still seems unnecessary. @Spycho's solution may be the solution to this.